# Publishing to multiple subscribes in RX

Tags: c#, .net, system.reactive

I am investigating how to develop a plugin framework for a project and Rx seems like a good fit for what i am trying to achieve. Ultimately, the project will be a set of plugins (modular functionality) that can be configured via xml to do different things. The requirements are as follows

1. Enforce a modular architecture even within a plugin. This encourages loose coupling and potentially minimizes complexity. This hopefully should make individual plugin functionality easier to model and test
2. Enforce immutability with respect to data to reduce complexity and ensure that state management within modules is kept to a minimum
3. Discourage manual thread creation by providing thread pool threads to do work within modules wherever possible

In my mind, a plugin is essentially a data transformation entity. This means a plugin either

- Takes in some data and transforms it in some way to produce new data (Not shown here)
- Generates data in itself and pushes it out to observers
- Takes in some data and does some work on the data without notifying outsiders

If you take the concept further, a plugin can consist of a number of all three types above.For example within a plugin you can have an IntGenerator module that generates some data to a ConsoleWorkUnit module etc. So what I am trying to model in the main function is the wiring that a plugin would have to do its work.

To that end, I have the following base classes using the Immutable nuget from Microsoft. What I am trying to achieve is to abstract away the Rx calls so they can be used in modules so the ultimate aim would be to wrap up calls to buffer etc in abstract classes that can be used to compose complex queries and modules. This way the code is a bit more self documenting than having to actually read all the code within a module to find out it subscribes to a buffer or window of type x etc.

```
public abstract class OutputBase<TOutput> : SendOutputBase<TOutput>
{
    public abstract void Work();
}

public interface IBufferedBase<TOutput>
{
    void Work(IList<ImmutableList<Data<TOutput>>> list);
}

public abstract class BufferedWorkBase<TInput> : IBufferedBase<TInput>
{
    public abstract void Work(IList<ImmutableList<Data<TInput>>> input);
}
public abstract class SendOutputBase<TOutput>
{
    private readonly ReplaySubject<ImmutableList<Data<TOutput>>> _outputNotifier;
    private readonly IObservable<ImmutableList<Data<TOutput>>> _observable;

    protected SendOutputBase()
    {
        _outputNotifier = new ReplaySubject<ImmutableList<Data<TOutput>>>(10);
        _observable  =  _outputNotifier.SubscribeOn(ThreadPoolScheduler.Instance);
        _observable = _outputNotifier.ObserveOn(ThreadPoolScheduler.Instance);
    }

    protected void SetOutputTo(ImmutableList<Data<TOutput>> output)
    {
        _outputNotifier.OnNext(output);
    }

    public void ConnectOutputTo(IWorkBase<TOutput> unit)
    {
        _observable.Subscribe(unit.Work);
    }

    public void BufferOutputTo(int count, IBufferedBase<TOutput> unit)
    {
        _observable.Buffer(count).Subscribe(unit.Work);
    }
}

public abstract class WorkBase<TInput> : IWorkBase<TInput>
{
    public abstract void Work(ImmutableList<Data<TInput>> input);
}

public interface IWorkBase<TInput>
{
    void Work(ImmutableList<Data<TInput>> input);
}

public class Data<T>
{
    private readonly T _value;

    private Data(T value)
    {
        _value = value;
    }

    public static Data<TData> Create<TData>(TData value)
    {
        return new Data<TData>(value);
    }

    public T Value { get { return _value; } }

}
```

These base classes are used to create three classes; one for generating some int data, one to print out the data when they occur and the last to buffer the data as it comes in and sum the values in threes.

```
public class IntGenerator : OutputBase<int>
{
    public override void Work()
    {
        var list = ImmutableList<Data<int>>.Empty;
        var builder = list.ToBuilder();
        for (var i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
        {
            builder.Add(Data<int>.Create(i));
        }

        SetOutputTo(builder.ToImmutable());
    }
}

public class ConsoleWorkUnit : WorkBase<int>
{
    public override void Work(ImmutableList<Data<int>> input)
    {
        foreach (var data in input)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("ConsoleWorkUnit printing {0}", data.Value);
        }
    }
}

public class SumPrinter : WorkBase<int>
{

    public override void Work(ImmutableList<Data<int>> input)
    {
        input.ToObservable().Buffer(2).Subscribe(PrintSum);
    }

    private void PrintSum(IList<Data<int>> obj)
    {
      Console.WriteLine("Sum of {0}, {1} is {2} ", obj.First().Value,obj.Last().Value ,obj.Sum(x=>x.Value) );
    }
}
```

These are run in a main like this

```
        var intgen = new IntGenerator();
        var cons = new ConsoleWorkUnit();
        var sumPrinter = new SumPrinter();

        intgen.ConnectOutputTo(cons);
        intgen.BufferOutputTo(3,sumPrinter);

        Task.Factory.StartNew(intgen.Work);

        Console.ReadLine();
```

Is this architecture sound?

Comment: I tried running your code, but couldn't find the definitions for `IBufferedBase<TOutput>` & `BufferedWorkBase<int>`. Can you add those please?

Comment: Also, Rx calls are almost always fluent - so calling this `_outputNotifier.SubscribeOn(ThreadPoolScheduler.Instance)` just returns a new `IObservable<ImmutableList<Data<TOutput>>>` that you throw away. The same with `_outputNotifier.ObserveOn(ThreadPoolScheduler.Instance)`. You might want to try fix those first.

Comment: @Enigmativity thanks for the response, updated with interfaces and changed code as suggested. Cheers Bernard

Comment: You still haven't got the fluent interface usage right. You're wiping out the `SubscribeOn` when you assign the `ObserveOn`.

Comment: I appreciate you posting the code. It appears that you are trying very hard to make Rx as hard as possible. Rx is a very functional (as in functional programming), but you're trying to make it object oriented. You're losing a lot of the power. Can you explain what you're trying to do here from a requirements POV and I think I can make it all much easier?

Comment: @Enigmativity, thanks for the compliment, i do like things difficult lol ;). I have updated the post with a set of requirements. I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are buffering your observable (`.Buffer(count)`) so that it only signals after `count` notifications arrive.

However, your `IntGenerator.DoWork` only ever produces a single value.  Thus you never "fill" the buffer and trigger downstream notifications.

Either change `DoWork` so that it eventually produces more values, or have it *complete* the observable stream when it finishes its work.  `Buffer` will release the remaining buffered values when the stream completes.  To do this, it means somewhere `IntGenerator.DoWork` needs to cause a call to `_outputNotifier.OnCompleted()`

Comment: thanks for that! You are absolutely right. I have updated the code and it works as expected. Would it be possible in my current architecture to buffer on the enumerable as its created which was my original intent?

Comment: i think your answer resolves the initial thrust of the question so Ill mark it as answered and create a new one. Thanks again for the help

Comment: Sorry, I've been away.  Instead of making an `Subject<ImmutableList<T>>` just make a `Subject<T>` and push individual items into it in your `DoWork` methods.  The resulting observable will be `IObservable<T>`.  At this point `Buffer` will have the desired effect of producing arrays of `count` items: `IObservable<T[]>`.   If you really want an `ImmutableList`, then follow `Buffer` with `.Select(b => ImmutableList.CreateRange(b))`